# Laravel Undefined offset: 1451

Tags: php, arrays, exception, laravel-5

I'm trying to sum some elements fetched from Database as Collection in a new created array and the code looks like

```
foreach ($demands as $demand) {

    $demandProject[$demand->projectid][$demand->week]['tickets'] += isset($demand->title) ? $demand->title : '';
    $demandProject[$demand->projectid][$demand->week]['total']   += (float) $demand->time;
    $demandProject[$demand->projectid][$demand->week]['l1']      += $demand->time_l1;
    $demandProject[$demand->projectid][$demand->week]['l2']      += $demand->time_l2;
    $demandProject[$demand->projectid][$demand->week]['l3']      += $demand->time_l3;
    $demandProject[$demand->projectid][$demand->week]['l4']      += $demand->time_l4;
    $demandProject[$demand->projectid][$demand->week]['l5']      += $demand->time_l5;
    $demandProject[$demand->projectid][$demand->week]['ns']      += $demand->time_ns;
}
```

but I'm getting

```
ErrorException
Undefined offset: 1451
```

what does that error mean what I'm doing wrong

Comment: You need to handle errors - the code is too optimistic. `if (isset($demandProject[$demand->projectid]) and isset($demandProject[$demand->projectid][$demand->week])) ... else ...`

Comment: thanks for feedback I got it between, I have to add a starter value if index is not defined yet